# c# WebBrowser, how I get page content of result page?

Tags: c#

I have a c# application with a WebBrowser component.

I set the documentText properties with a string that contains a form and an autosubmit to another page:

In the application the code is:

```
private void carica_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
browserRoar.DocumentText = formHTML;
browserRoar.DocumentCompleted += new     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(ShowDocument);
}

private void ShowDocument(object sender,WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
string newContent = (browserRoar.DocumentText);
}
```

In the webbrowser i see that the new page is the one with results but when i check newContent i find the starting content. How can i get the new content?
Thanks
Fulvio

Comment: Using a while loop containing DoEvents just killed a kitten. Look at the [WebBrowser.DocumentCompleted event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: I changed using DocumentCompleted but when I call the function after completion i get always the same result

Comment: Please edit the new code into your question and remove the old code.

Comment: I edited and inserted the new code

Comment: "autosubmit" does not do much to help us help you.  But you are likely to need a variable to count the number of DocumentCompleted events.  The first time it fires will be from your DocumentText property assignment.  So of course you just see back what you assigned.  If that navigates elsewhere somehow then you need the *second* event.